# how to know what objects in grid column and grid row wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, grid

so i make some game now

and i divide My grid with ColumnDefinitions and RowDefinitions

and i want to know What objects(Button,Images) in a particular cell

someone can help?

exemple(For example here in the first three Cells is nothing

And the rest has a button
How can I know it with c # code

If I can only know a certain cell for example in this picture is 1,0 it is also ok)

[image]

Comment: https://www.wpf-tutorial.com/panels/grid-rows-and-columns/

Comment: what am i see here?

Comment: How to place an element in a specific row and column.

Comment: its not my question

Comment: my question is how to see the location in c# code

Comment: Then why don't you know in which position the element is in? Aren't you placing it in the grid yourself?

Comment: i am
but he is moving...

Comment: Ah. But then you would only need to know the x-y position of the element and the width and height of a cell and calculate the position.

Comment: that is not a problem
My problem is knowing by row and column what objects are there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The things in a grid are in it's children collection.

The tricky part is that a cell is purely logical.

The cell is defined by the attached properties grid.row and grid.column.

You can therefore check these.

Roughly:

```
 var elements = MyGrid.Children
                 .Cast<UIElement>()
                  .Where(el=> Grid.GetRow(el) == r && Grid.GetColumn(el)==c);
```

Where r is zero based row and c is zero based column of your cell.